# How to install/apply downloaded theme I got on magento 2.1.5?

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, download-link

I've tried to find any article to installing downloaded themes, but no one is right on my magento version,

I've extracted themes from external link and I got 3 folder :

- add-ons
- magento_files
- theme_content

inside of those folder has too much folder, so I'm confused what the right folder to installing the theme,

[here is the link to download the theme](http://www.buzzthemes.com/downloadable/download/link/id/MzQtZmxpeC5yZXNpZ25AZ21haWwuY29t/)

please help me how to installing themes

Comment: Could you please share the directory structure screenshot for each folder

Comment: @PankajPareek I've share my downloaded link about the theme so anyone can see the structure of the directory, I can't share all the path of each folder, too much directory,

Comment: link is redirecting to login screen. Only three screenshot you need to share for each directory that you mentioned

Comment: I'm on the way to reupload the file, on each folder I've opened, there are about 3-4 folder anymore of total 2k files & folder,

Comment: can you share `magento_files` folder screenshot only ? are you uploading files in m2 installtion ?

Comment: [here's a screenshot](https://snag.gy/eglVtc.jpg) of `magento_files`, and in each folder has `app, js, skin` folder, I've tried to copy `1.9.x` folder to magento folder root but the theme not showing. [download link of file](https://ufile.io/ujn6d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theme Files that you have downloaded is incorrect for Magento 2 installation. As per shared screenshot, It is for `Magento 1.x` version not for `M2 version`.

You need to download the Magento 2.1 version theme files.

Comment: so the other way is i need to download new theme or reinstall magento to lower version?
 can you tell me step-by-step to installing downloaded theme also?

Comment: best way is to download the M2 compatible theme. You need to copy theme files in magento directories and after running cache clean and need to enable theme from backend. this may helpful https://magenticians.com/magento-2-install-theme/ https://blog.landofcoder.com/magento-2-install-theme-manually/